# Checking of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

While compactness & connectedness are preserved under continuous maps, this question comes to my mind:
$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is strictly monotone increasing function such that {$ f(x) : x \in \mathbb R$} is dense in $\mathbb R$ , then prove or disprove, that: $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A strictly monotonic function can only have jump discontinuities (try proving this, or read a proof at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139264/montone-function-only-has-jump-discontinuities)), and a jump discontinuity would imply that the image set isn't dense; so $f$ must be continuous.

Comment: @ T.Bongers... you are saying that: if the function has jump discontinuity then the image can't be dense... But if it is given that the image set is dense, can you say anything about the function??

Comment: @user92360 Yes, it must be continuous by the contrapositive. Not continuous $\implies$ image is not dense.

Comment: @T.Bongers...hmm.... thank you!!