# How do you prove that a monotone function can only have jump discontinuities?

Tags: real-analysis

I've already seen this link - [Montone Function only has Jump Discontinuities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139264/montone-function-only-has-jump-discontinuities) - but I'm having trouble 'filling in the blanks' in the proof.

Would anyone be able to walk me through a complete proof of this? I've been struggling for several hours now..

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality assume it is non-decreasing.

At the point $x=a$ the $\lim_{x\to a-}f(x)$ is bounded by $f(a)$ from above and $f$ increases in $(-\infty,a)$. Therefore the lateral limit from the left exists. On the other hand $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)$ is bounded from below by $f(a)$ and $f$ increases in $(a,+\infty)$. Therefore the lateral limit from the right exists.